# Confusion about column types in dbunit and creating dtd for datasets

Tags: java, dataset, dbunit, assertion

I would appreciate some help with using dbunit.
I use postgresql9 as db.

I created table book using hibernate's hbm2ddl tool.

I wanted to create some xmldatasets for testing with dbunit.Using the ant DBUnit task I exported values from db to a 
initialdataset.xml ,which I clean-insert to db before every test.Deleting some rows ,I created an expecteddataset.xml. If I am to compare a table created from db 
with a table created from expecteddataset.xml ,I think I need to define a dtd.I used the following code to create dtd.

```
public static void createDTD(String dtdFileName) throws FileNotFoundException...{
        IDatabaseConnection connection = DbUnitUtils.createConnection();
        FlatDtdDataSet.write(connection.createDataSet(),new FileWriter("data/dbunit/"+dtdFileName));
        connection.close();
}
...
createDTD("myschema.dtd");
```

The created dtd is given below

```
...
<!ELEMENT book EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST book
    book_id CDATA #REQUIRED
    isbn CDATA #REQUIRED
    book_name CDATA #REQUIRED
    publish_date CDATA #IMPLIED
    price CDATA #REQUIRED
    description CDATA #IMPLIED
    publisher_id CDATA #IMPLIED
    author_id CDATA #IMPLIED
>
...
```

expecteddataset.xml is like this-[expecteddataset xml](http://pastebin.com/dGn5fpYN)

My postgres db table 'book' is of the form

```
   Column    |          Type          | Modifiers 
--------------+------------------------+-----------
 book_id      | bigint                 | not null
 isbn         | character varying(255) | not null
 book_name    | character varying(255) | not null
 publish_date | date                   | 
 price        | real                   | not null
 description  | character varying(255) | 
 publisher_id | bigint                 | 
 author_id    | bigint                 | 
Indexes:
    "book_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (book_id)
    "book_isbn_key" UNIQUE, btree (isbn)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk1f32e959a9fc15" FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES author(author_id)
    "fk1f32e9b6bbf81f" FOREIGN KEY (publisher_id) REFERENCES publisher(publisher_id)
```

What confuses me is that the publish_date field(which is a date type in postgres) , book_id( bigint type),price(real type)
are also treated as CDATA.How can a table made from fields which are String types equal to a table retrieved from db which
have fields varying as Long,Date etc?

In testcode I tried

```
removeSomeRowsFromBookTable();
ITable actualBookTable = connection.createQueryTable("book", "select BOOK_ID,ISBN,...from BOOK");
IDataSet expectedDataSet = DbUnitUtils.createDataSet("expecteddataset.xml.xml");
ITable expectedBookTable = expectedDataSet.getTable("book");
Assert.assertEquals(expectedBookTable, actualBookTable);
```

This causes AssertionFailedError.

The stacktrace is

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 

expected:<org.dbunit.dataset.DefaultTable@12d8ecd> 

but was:<org.dbunit.database.CachedResultSetTable@1fa5e5e>

at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
    at junit.framework.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:282)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:64)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:71)
    at myapp.test.cascades.HibernateCascadeTests.testCascading(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:76)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:673)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:846)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1170)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1147)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:749)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:600)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:317)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:274)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:223)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:964)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:900)
    at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1182)
    at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1146)
```

Is there something wrong in what I am doing here?Do I have to provide some info about the column types for the table elements?
If someone can help me solve this,it would be nice.

DbUnitUtils class to create datasets

```
class DbUnitUtils {
    public static IDatabaseConnection createConnection(){
        ...
    }  
    public static IDataSet createDataSet(String file) throws DataSetException, IOException{
        return new FlatXmlDataSet(new File("data/dbunit/"+file));
    }
}
```

p.s:
I tried this with dbunit-2.2.2 and 2.4.8 versions with same results..So, it must be that I am missing something vital to running dbunit properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was because `junit Assert` does not know about equality of Dbunit classes(`ITable` etc) and was failing in assertEquals()..I should have used  `assertEquals() from dbunit's Assertion class`.

such a simple overlook of basic facts..caused me couple of days ' grief

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing the objects themselves rather than the contents. You might want to look at something like [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/) which is really geared towards this kind of testing. Also EasyMock will help break the dependency of actually using a database.